# Why is connecting to Firebase giving my application an issue from Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-realtime-database

build.gradle (app):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.grade (Project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Google services and Google repositories are all up to date as per the SDK.

I am getting the following error:

```
Error:(42, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.gms.google-services']
   > Version: 7.5.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.
```

I am trying to connect to Firebase from my app and I have the `google-services.json` file inside the `app` folder.

How can I resolve the issue to connect to Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

> ```
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
> ```

to

> ```
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
> ```

In conclusion:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Update google play service version  number on build.gradle file

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: use same version of fire base and google play services version number and also update your  play services on SDK  manager.

Comment: Ahhhhhh... the version has to be same for google-services and firebase?

Comment: There is nowhere in the documentation it said that... *SIGH*!!! Thank you