# Why can't my project see Firebase as an import

Tags: android, firebase

I was successfully able to get Firebase to implement in my app: [Why is connecting to Firebase giving my application an issue from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340324/why-is-connecting-to-firebase-giving-my-application-an-issue-from-android-studio)

Now that I goto my project MainActivity, i tried to enter the following:

```
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
```

I get an error in `firebase`:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'firebase'
```

When I tried this in my MainActivity:

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
```

I get the same error message above and it is asking me to create a Firebase class.

How can I resolve the issue so my app can see Firebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using new version of Firebase but those are the imports of old version of firebase..
New version imports will look like this

```
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.MutableData;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;
import com.google.firebase.database.Transaction;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
```

Just remove those imports Ide will prompt for importing new classes

Comment: My App wont see database either, any ideas why?

Comment: if IDE is unable to find database class, make sure you integrate firebase correctly https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 1):

In the new SDK, it's no longer necessary to call

> Firebase.setAndroidContext()

so you can remove it from your code.

Look here:

https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#setting_the_android_context_and_enabling_offline_persistence_numbered

Comment: Quick question, I am saving "Name", "Date", "Value", "Location", {another column} to a Sqlite Db locally. At the same time, I would also like to save that row to Firebase. While looking at the doc it only allows me to save key/value pair. So should it be, "Name: Value", "Date: Value"...?

Comment: `private DatabaseReference mDatabase;` then I have this `mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Config.FIREBASE_URL);` and then finally I am calling the following to save the value: `mDatabase.setValue(etfdate.getText().toString());`. I get the following error: `Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.` any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358339/why-is-firebase-failing-to-initialize